# JQuery Mobile Sliding Panel with nested menu/ multi-level menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, razor, panel

I have been working on multi-level menu's or sub-menu's on my jquery mobile and generally 3rd partly jquery plugins have been deeply messing with my CSS relating to `position:fixed` footer and scrolling.

I looked at the [plugin's here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/side%20menu/) and almost all of them are complicating things for me. I was hoping I could recreate [this example](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/) with some magic from the existing jquery mobile framework as [seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/UHYz9/6/)

Comment: You can create multiple content div inside panel and slide them on request. I'll give you an example tomorrow.

Comment: @Omar taking a queue from your hint, I am up to here http://jsfiddle.net/UHYz9/9/. The problem is how do I get the overlay of one panel on the other?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qUMbC/

Comment: yep, pretty much what I wanted. Thanks, plz post as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: btw, the demo is updated again. I'm glad it helped, I'll post an answer and will update it with more features :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Left-hand Panel and submenus:

Here is a fast solution just to give you an idea. It has big room for improvement, so I will update this answer whenever I do any changes.

Create Submenus as much as you want, each one with a *unique id* and a close button with a *class*. Place Submenus inside main jQM panel.

1. **Submenu HTML structure**

   ```
   <div class='ui-sub-panel' id='submenu1'>
     <div class='ui-header' data-theme='a'>
       <a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete panel-close'>Close</a>
       <h1 class='ui-title'>Submenu1</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-content">
       <!-- submenu contents here -->
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. **CSS**

   - Full height, width and positioned outside page.

     ```
     .ui-sub-panel {
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: -100%;
       min-height: 100%;
       max-height: none;
     }
     ```
   - Open Submenu

     ```
     .ui-sub-panel-open {
       -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
       transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
     }
     ```
   - Close Submenu

     ```
     .ui-sub-panel-close{
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     }
     ```
   - Animate close/open

     ```
     .ui-sub-panel-animate {
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
       transition: transform 500ms ease;
     }
     ```
3. **JS**

   - Close all submenus once main jQM panel is closed

     ```
     $("#externalpanel").on("panelbeforeclose", function () {
       $('#submenu1, #submenu2')
           .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
           .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
     });
     ```
   - Open first submenu

     ```
     $('.sub1').on('click', function () {
       $('#submenu1')
           .addClass('ui-sub-panel-open ui-sub-panel-animate')
           .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-close");
     });
     ```
   - Open second submenu

     ```
     $('.sub2').on('click', function () {
       $('#submenu2')
          .addClass('ui-sub-panel-open ui-sub-panel-animate')
          .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-close");
     });
     ```
   - Close Submenu where *close* button is clicked

     ```
     $('.panel-close').on('click', function () {
       $(this)
          .closest(".ui-sub-panel")
          .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
          .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
     });
     ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qUMbC/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

---

> ### Update 1

#### Right-hand Panel and submenus:

To position panel to right side, add `data-position="right"` attribute to panel div. Also, in `.ui-sub-panel` class, change `left` to `right`.

```
.ui-sub-panel {
   ...
   right: -100%;
   ...
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uH3jp/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

---

<sup>(1) Tested on Safari - iPhone 5 iOS 7.0.6 & iPad 2 iOS 7.1</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to capture the event of the panelbeforeclose and actually keep the panel open and overlay another panel on top of the existing panel instead of using divs? This solution is a good alternative, but I am just thinking of alternative ways to achieve the soln.

Comment: In this case, submenus should be placed outside jQM main panel. They will be hidden once panel is closed. You can keep them open but _hidden_, they will show once main panel is open. if this is what you want, skip `panelbeforeclose` part. @Shouvik

Comment: so I tried to prevent the panel from closing using the `beforeclose` event. Unfortunately, I think jquery events are linked for when a panel is open and another needs to be opened, the first needs to be closed. This is probably the reason why i get a stackexceded error.

Comment: @Shouvik You want to keep panel open all the time? Could you please elaborate on what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Similar to what you have achieved by clicking submenu 3, but instead of using a div. I have placed the panel outside like I had elaborated here. http://jsfiddle.net/UHYz9/9/. Since I use a data-role=panel, I would like the previous panel from closing and the new panel to be an overlay on the previous panel like this example http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/

Comment: The main reason behind doing this is, I would like the CSS to take effect from the same div panel design instead of customizing my own CSS for each div. I realize that I can put the same classes on the div, but that would involve me manually intervening on section when I update the class name liked to a default panel.

Comment: @Shouvik note that in jQM it's not possible to have two active panels at the same time. Before opening a panel, it checks if another panel is open, if true, it closes it and then open a panel. if you want to have more than panel opened at the same time, you need to modify _panel widget_. IMHO, adding your custom panels is safer and easier.

Comment: This looks like what I also require. Any way to make the sub menu panels slide in from the right rather than the left?

Comment: @totalitarian I'll update my answer, check it in 5 mins.

Comment: Thanks Omar, it's not quite what I wanted. I still want the original panel to slide in from the left, but the sub panels to slide in from the right.

Comment: @totalitarian oh, I misunderstood you then. I'll let you know once i update answer again.

Comment: Thanks, btw the new demo you just posted didn't work on my iPhone safari/chrome, although it did work on chrome desktop

Comment: @totalitarian http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Np9G8/ is this what you want? btw, all demos were tested on both ipad 2 - safari and iphone 5 - safari.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. Just out of interest, is it possible to remember which panel is open after the overlay is clicked? Of we are at sub panel 2 and click the content area to close all panels, can we have it so clicking the button again will bring us back to the same sub menu panel?

Comment: @totalitarian It is possible; simplest way is to add custom class to last open one and remove that class from previous open one (if any). I cant update my answer with such details, the post will look crowded. If you want, post an answer and I'll show you how to achieve it :)

Comment: @totalitarian haha, I meant a question. my mistake!

Comment: @totalitarian if my find my answer helpful, thumb it up ;)

Comment: @totalitarian thanks :) if you have more question, feel free to post them to get them answered.

Comment: New question created here thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593638/enhancing-a-jquery-mobile-menu-system