# Loading HTML in <div> before .ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

At first I'm using JQuery Mobile. I have already investigated about loading HTML inside a div but I having some problems.

The main idea is that I have 3 differents menus (which are lists) and each one stored in a HTML file generated by the server. /Menu1.html, /Menu2.html, /Menu3.html. It has to be this way because menus could change dynamically.

So, the menus looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <il><a href="whatever1> Option1 </a></li>
    <ul>
      <il><a href="whatever1> Option1.1 </a></li>
    </ul>
  <il><a href="whatever2> Option2 </a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
    <div id="menuview">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#menuview").load("data/menu1.html");
    </script>
```

And it is loading the list, right, but without css. So What I'm seeing is just the list and not a JQM linked list view like the demo here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview/

If I copy the menu1.html inside the div manually it works perfectly.
I'm not just asking for a solution, maybe is there any better way to do this and I don't know it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When using jQuery Mobile, you must initialize any content that gets added after jQuery Mobile first initializes. I think you can call `.trigger("create")` on the new element once its in the DOM. My knowledge of jQuery Mobile is old by now so you may need to look up in the documentation exactly how to initialize HTML fragments like this.

Comment: This is a nested listview which is removed in jQM 1.4. Anyway, you need to initialize it manually.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Omar, how could I implement a menu with sub levels like in the example? Now, initialized, it is working. So, better ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Jasper it's good to see you around. `.trigger("create")` is replaced with `.enhanceWithin()`, just fyi :)

Comment: @Omar I haven't used jQM in a while, I assumed they've changed quite a bit. Am I still at the top of the list for answers in the jQM tag :)?

Comment: @Jasper you're second, you have given great answers. you haven't been forgotten, dont worry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding any items dynamically, you need to initialize them manually.

Inside each *menu* you have, add *initialization* function.

```
<ul>
 <!-- elements -->
 <script>
  $(function () {
    $("ul").listview();
  });
 </script>
</ul>
```

Note that *nested listview* is removed from jQM 1.4.

To create a *nested listview*, check [this official demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-nested-lists/).

Comment: Sorry for bother you again, Omar. Do you now how can I initialize a nestedlist? I have asked in its github forum but I didn't get any answer and I have tried with .nestedlist(); but it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 Nested listview is deprecated as of jQM 1.3, but here's an official demo by jQM http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/listview-nested-lists/ it has no function `.nestedlist()` isn't a function, as it's not a widget by itself. It falls under listview widget.

Comment: Well, I have downloaded it and I'm using it. The problem is that when I load the menu.html (with the script you wrote in this answer) it loads the regular list view and not the nested one. If I paste into the html and I don't load it from the file it works OK. My theory is that when I execute $("ul").listview(); I'm initializing the regular one and no the nested. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 in this case inside _menu.html_ add `<script>$(function () { ("ul").listview(); });</script>`

Comment: Sorry for my english because I think I'm explaining me bad =(. I thank you the effort. I already have that in my menu.html and it is executed but it loads the regular listview: http://imgur.com/vBIU3GY when it supposed to be nested: http://imgur.com/uiQaAd6

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 oh I got what you mean now. You cant do this because nested list are converted into _pages_. why dont use panels? for example this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/20900548/1771795

Comment: Wow! it looks great. I'm going to check it out, it could be the best solution! thanks for your help!