# How to nest panels independently in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am struggling to get two jQuery mobile panels working independently. Essentially the page has one main (navigation) panel and a content container. The content container also has a panel within the container.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> <a href="#menu-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Cancel</a> 
         <h1>Home</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel" data-display="push">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="panel" id="sub-panel" data-display="push">
            <p>Sub Panel</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content"> <a href="#sub-panel">Toggle sub-panel</a>

            <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been dabbling with the layout structure and jQuery hacks for hours trying to reach a valid solution to no avail. After going through the jQuery mobile code, I found an event listener that is most likely the culprit:

```
// line 13258 jquery.mobile.js
...
this.document.on( "panelbeforeopen", function( e ) {
    if ( self._open && e.target !== self.element[ 0 ] ) {
        self.close();
    }
})
...
```

I thought simply unbinding the listener ( `$(document).unbind('panelbeforeopen');` ) would work but it created a rather unexpected result. It would reverse the nature of the panels so that after a few clicks you would need to `open()` to `close()` and vise versa.

I've also tried stopping event propagation on the panels but that did not work either.

I have created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/etdyfcux/)** to aid in debugging.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can create multi-level panels http://stackoverflow.com/a/20900548/1771795 http://stackoverflow.com/a/22593969/1771795

Comment: Well written question.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to create a workaround via tip from @Omar. This fork instead creates a nest in the content, not within the panel. Provided below for future devs.

#### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> <a href="#menu-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Cancel</a> 
         <h1>Home</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel" data-display="push">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class='ui-sub-panel' id='submenu1'>
            <div class='ui-header' data-theme='a'> <a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete panel-close'>Close</a>

                 <h1 class='ui-title'>Submenu1</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="ui-content">
                <!-- submenu contents here -->
                Sub content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-sub-content">
            <a href="#" class='sub1'>Submenu 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

#### CSS

```
.ui-sub-panel {
    width: 17em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -17em;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: none;
}
.ui-sub-panel-open {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(17em, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(17em, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(17em, 0, 0);
}
.ui-sub-panel-animate {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
    transition: transform 300ms ease;
}
.ui-sub-panel-close {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.ui-sub-content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

#### JS

```
/* open submenu1 */
$('.sub1').on('click', function () {
    $('#submenu1')
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-open ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-close");
    $('.ui-sub-content')
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-open ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass('ui-sub-panel-close');
});

/* close panel where close button is clicked */
$('.panel-close').on('click', function () {
    $(this)
        .closest(".ui-sub-panel")
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
    $('.ui-sub-content')
        .addClass('ui-sub-panel-close ui-sub-panel-animate')
        .removeClass("ui-sub-panel-open");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/etdyfcux/2/)